# GridSearchCV: Specifying F1 Score For Class = 1 (Updated: Make_Scorer)

Tags: python, grid-search

EDIT: Thanks to Chinny, I am going to change my question just a bit:

Context: I am working with a set of data with a binary target variable. The 1 only makes up 10% of the data, so while I have used some techniques (such as down-sampling) when using GridSearchCV I would like to score only on metrics surrounding Class 1.

For example, my best model might be chosen as one with 0.98 recall for class 0 and 0.28 recall for class 1, with a 0.91 overall since Class 0 outnumbers Class 1 by such a great amount.

I would prefer to choose the model with a 0.93 recall of Class 0, 0.58 of Class 1, and 0.85 recall overall.

Here is a simple example of my set-up:

```
    param_grid = {'n_estimators':[100,200,300,400],
       'random_state':[1]}

    extra_tree_Grid = GridSearchCV(et, param_grid, cv = 5, scoring = "f1",   
    refit = True, n_jobs=2, verbose = 5)
    extra_tree_Grid.fit(X_train_new, y_train_new.ravel())
```

Chinny84 recommended I look into "make_scorer" function, and I played around with this a bit but kept getting the same outputs as I would get if I just used the "f1" or "recall" that already exist for the scoring parameter of GridSearchCV.

Or, I get an error. Here is an example of what I would like (not actually coded)

```
    from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, recall_score, make_scorer

    def custom_recall(y_true, y_pred):
        'filter for class 1 for both y_true and y_pred' 
        'target_accuracy = (y_pred Class 1 & are Class 1) / y_true Class 1'
        return target_accuracy

    my_scorer = make_scorer(custom_recall)
```

I thought that I could pull a specific class out of the metric "recall" that exists, in this case I would want to pull those that were of class 1, but I am getting pretty lost in how to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst a scoring function may exist in the sklearn library, you can definitely make your own scorer (assuming your base model admits such functions).

Take a look at this method from sklearn - [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html).

Comment: Thanks Chinny - I actually am looking into that now and struggling a bit, but I will follow-up on the documentation and report back if I find something!

Comment: Ok, feed back if you have issues - but update your question with your new question (if you indeed have one)